# Use of the Oracle tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking at the questions tagged with an [oracle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle) tag and they seem to fall into two categories:

- A question related to Oracle Enterprise Linux
- A question regarding an issue with Oracle database on another Linux distribution

Should the tag be applied only to questions pertaining to OEL rather than Oracle database? Perhaps some clarification in the tag description or wiki would help.

Thoughts?

Comment: Dash here, and dash there: [tag:oracle-el] for the OS and [tag:oracle-db] for the, um... database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

34 questions tagged [oracle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle). Let's break them down by topic.

#### Oracle Linux [3]

- [Add a new user steps for Oracle Linux 5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72026/add-a-new-user-steps-for-oracle-linux-5)
- [Bonding configuration on a blade server with Oracle 6.3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78783/bonding-configuration-on-a-blade-server-with-oracle-6-3)
- [Oracle Linux 6 download files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85348/oracle-linux-6-download-files)

#### Oracle database (any edition) [15]

- [fedora 15, oracle 11, python3: can't find or open libclntsh.so.11.1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14797/fedora-15-oracle-11-python3-cant-find-or-open-libclntsh-so-11-1)
- [fedora 15, oracle 11: can't login using sqlplus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14814/fedora-15-oracle-11-cant-login-using-sqlplus)
- [Oracle 11g database startup automation on Fedora 15](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16691/oracle-11g-database-startup-automation-on-fedora-15)
- [Where to get 32-bit Oracle-XE 11g binaries?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21009/where-to-get-32-bit-oracle-xe-11g-binaries)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28660/how-to-backup-and-restore-oracle-10g-express-in-linux-vps
- [How to install Oracle on Arch Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29397/how-to-install-oracle-on-arch-linux)
- [AIX 6.1 JFS2 Oracle files system, not using much files system cache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44524/aix-6-1-jfs2-oracle-files-system-not-using-much-files-system-cache)
- [Installing rpm & dependencies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44976/installing-rpm-dependencies)
- [Why is connecting to Oracle Express 11 is very slow on Fedora 17?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59224/why-is-connecting-to-oracle-express-11-is-very-slow-on-fedora-17)
- [How to check how many Oracle user sessions are running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60518/how-to-check-how-many-oracle-user-sessions-are-running)
- [Oracle 11gR2 grid silent installation: error for privateinterconnects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75231/oracle-11gr2-grid-slient-installation-error-for-privateinterconnects)
- [How to remove Oracle Wallet using orapki?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72855/how-to-remove-oracle-wallet-using-orapki)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75958/how-to-run-oracle10g-forms-in-browser-in-linux
- [How to Install Oracle 11gR2 on Ubuntu Server 13.04](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79367/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-on-ubuntu-server-13-04)
- [Can not start Oracle after installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79488/can-not-start-oracle-after-complete-the-installation)

#### Oracle VM Server [4]

- [What does a "OVM reboot" mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1244/what-does-a-ovm-reboot-mean) (?)
- [Difference between Oracle VM and Citrix XEN?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38266/difference-between-oracle-vm-and-citrix-xen)
- [Where can I find updated TAR.rpm for Oracle VM Server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78576/where-can-i-find-updated-tar-rpm-for-oracle-vm-server)
- [How to do incremental backup of .img files containing windows partition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78919/how-to-do-incremental-backup-of-img-files-containing-windows-partition)

#### Removed Oracle tag

These questions had the [oracle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle) tag but it was irrelevant:

- [The future of OpenSolaris](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/the-future-of-opensolaris) (Solaris)
- [Shell Script Certification](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2341/shell-script-certification) (it's about professional certifications for programmers; vaguely associated with Oracle as a company, but via Solaris)
- [Find out global zone Name once you logged into a NON global zone](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21725/find-out-global-zone-name-once-you-logged-into-a-non-global-zone) (Solaris)
- [Is Oracle Solaris UNIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38938/is-oracle-solaris-unix) (Solaris)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53444/all-memory-not-showing-up (Oracle Linux, but the distribution is irrelevant)
- [Are limits.conf values applied on a per-process basis?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55319/are-limits-conf-values-applied-on-a-per-process-basis) (database, but the application was irrelevant)
- [How do I safely perform the below changes to network parameters on Solaris 10?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65428/how-do-i-safely-perform-the-below-changes-to-network-parameters-on-solaris-10) (Hyperion)
- [What's technical difference between official virtualbox and VirtualBox-OSE?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65937/whats-technical-difference-between-official-virtualbox-and-virtualbox-ose) (VirtualBox)
- [Renaming or making filenames unique](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81612/renaming-or-making-filenames-unique) (Oracle Linux, but the distribution is irrelevant)

---

The database wins hands down, a large majority of the questions where the [oracale](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracale) tag is useful use it to mean Oracle 10g or 11g or XE and associated tools. So if we keep that tag , it should mean the database.

Nonetheless, due to the inherent ambiguity, I favor getting rid of the tag and replacing it by more specific tags: [oracle-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-linux), [oracle-database](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-database), [oracle-vm-server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-vm-server).

Answer (score 1):

I would say rather than that the oracle-tag has to be defined. I will give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

Won't you find a lot of the Oracle questions in the DBA group anyway?